# Display Toast in Password LockScreen

Tags: android, toast, lockscreen

I want to display a Toast in Android's default Password LockScreen, such as:

```
Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Invalid password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

However, this toast actually appears in home screen instead of lockscreen. I think this toast is hidden by the keyguard. 
I also found that `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED` can be used to display something on top of the lockscreen. My obstacle is that it requires getWindow() in an activity to set this flag, however, default LockScreen in Android framework does not have an activity.
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: did you find the way to solve the problem for now? I have the same issue as yours.

Answer (score 0):

this is how I did it....

In code do the followings..

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast,  null);  // toast is a custom layout for the toast message
Toast t= new Toast(getApplicationContext());
t.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
t.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
t.setView(layout);
t.show();
```

I think this is the answer you wanted.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried this code. Firstly, getApplicationContext() return null. So I used: Toast t = new Toast(mContext) instead. However, this custom toast is still hidden by the keyguard.

Comment: which version of sdk are you using? in ics I just tested as a simple test ( run this code after locking the screen ). And it is working fine. Can you please check your custom layout

Comment: did u implement it as an independent application or added it in Android framework?

Comment: one more note: this bug occurs on Android framework version 4.1.2, Toast displays ok on Android 4.1.1_r6. It causes by some modification on WindowAnimator.java.